# client server between C++ and Python programs using boost-asio

Tags: python, c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am  beginner in C++.  Please give me advise and say what I am doing wrong.  I have to create  client server communication  Python client, C++ server.  I have created server on C++ it works, but I can communicate only using telnet with it. My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  const int SERVER_PORT = 50013;

  try {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint     endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),SERVER_PORT);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);

    std::cout << "Server ready" << std::endl;
    {
      acceptor.accept(socket);
      int foo [5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 }; 
      boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(foo));
      socket.close();
    }
  }
  catch(std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() <<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I want to communicate with it through the client Python :

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 50013                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close()                   # Close the socket when done
```

But I don't have any result on my client

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't have any result on my client

You have, but you interpreting it wrong:

```
s.connect((host, port))
print binascii.hexlify(s.recv(1024))
```

Result:

```
10000000020000004d00000028000000272f0000
```